# JQUERY post not working intermittently

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have included follwoing libraies in my asp.net files following some few plugins

```
//below is jQuery JavaScript Library v1.6.4
  <script src="Scripts/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
//below is  jQuery JavaScript Library v1.5.2  
    <script type='text/javascript' src="../Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
// below is jQuery UI 1.8.16
    <script type='text/javascript' src="../Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

now i have a post method in following code on my page

```
     $(document).ready(function () {

         var id = '<%=objLoginUser.UserId%>';
         var postUrl = 'UserManagement.aspx?id=-1&email=<%=objLoginUser.EmailId%>';
         if ($(document)[0].URL.indexOf("UserList.aspx") < 0 && $(document)[0].URL.indexOf("ReportOutput.aspx") < 0) {
             if ($(document)[0].URL.indexOf("Login.aspx") > -1) {
                 postUrl = postUrl + "&login=1";
             }
             else {
                 postUrl = postUrl + "&login=0";
             }
             **$.post(postUrl, {},
                                 function (data) {

                                     var val = data;
                                     val = val.replace(/__VIEWSTATE/gi, "STATE1");
                                     val = val.replace(/__EVENTVALIDATION/gi, "VALIDATE1");
                                     $("div#divUM1").html(val);
                                 });**
         }

         if ('<%=objLoginUser.EmailId%>' != '') {
             $("#lnkChangeProfile").click(function () {
                 ShowEditUserProfileBox('<%=objLoginUser.EmailId%>', id);
             });
         }
         else {

             $("#lnkChangeProfile").hide('fast');
         }

     });
```

This Post method works intermittently, some times when i remove/add some files or compile the project this stops working. Then i apply debugger inside this post method and do some editing and its starts working fine.

Is there some binding of Jquery with VS2010 project which get tampered and recovers later due to some reason.

Surprisingly when i debug it doed not break rather pass through the entire code but is does not go inside "**function (data) {}**". When it is working fine it goes inside "function (data) {" aslo and show value in data.

Please Suggest.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Could you explain why you are referencing two versions of jQuery? This could cause you a lot of grief!